# Terraform apigatewayv2 IP protection (lambda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way to IP Protect the HTTP API Endpoint of the API Gateway?

I tried to add an IAM Policy that allows IP's to the Lambda execution role but that didn't seem to work.

This is the high level structure of the API.

Route 53 Domain --> API Gateway V2 --> Lambda

I know the V1 (REST API) has functionality for a Resource based policy, but is there something similar for the V2 HTTP API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there something similar for the V2 HTTP API?

There is not. [Only REST API supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) resource policies, as well as WAF. But you could setup Amazon Cognito for HTTP API, if you don't want to switch to REST API.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking to add an authentication layer over the HTTP API. So I think the best way forward is to migrate to the V1 REST API?

Comment: @Bram Yes, I think so. REST API has the features (Resource based) that you want.